# Deployed Nodejs application with Mongodb cant be reached through REST API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've created an application with NodeJs and MongoDB.

When its deployed in server i'm not able to access it via http://domainname:poratnumber via REST API.

The deployed mongodb running instance :
[image: mongodb running instance]

Configuration settings in NodeJs as follows

```
var server = app.listen(4220, function () {
var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;
console.log('running at http://' + host + ':' + port)
});
```

Database connection string inside config/db.config.js

```
module.exports = {
url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'
}
```

When i hit http://domainname:4220/api/apiservice,

I'm getting The Requested URL cant be reached.

and i've also tried by hitting with IP address instead of domain name still same result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
-Vijay

Comment: The instance was running successfully, not sure why the attached image is not showing up here. Running at http://::::4200 image(https://imgur.com/LmovB95)

Comment: Your REST api is on 4220, your pinging port 4200 no?

Comment: @Vijay : Is that 4200  a typo in question ? (Vs) server is running on 4220 ? And why are you thinking it's cause of DB, if your site is not reachable ?

Comment: Ya sorry, its typo. actually its 4220 only. I've edited my question. I'm not sure what could be the problem bcoz its runnning successfully. i'm not able to connect with REST API thats my problem

Comment: Hey, have you written route you are requesting?

Comment: Yes, i've written routes. basically the API i'm trying call is to register a user which will bypass middleware as well. Its the same setup which i'm running in my localhost.
const userRoute         = require('./routes/user.route');
// RESTful API root
app.use('/api', userRoute);

Comment: check your server provider's security group sometimes you have to allow ports to accept incoming request, port 80, 22. 422 are open by default since the port number  you are using is a bit unconventional so i suggest u to check those settings.

Comment: i tried changing it to 422 now, no luck. i also checked by running these commands i)sudo lsof -i -P -n and ii) netstat -tuplen which shows the status of port i'm deploying is listening.

Comment: Guys, its the port giving issues. i think the provider didnt opened it when they said its opened. when asked for second time and tried it worked. thanks all for your help :)